# Access to mysql container from other container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have setup docker container with mysql that expose 3306.
I've specified database user, database password and create a test db and give the privileges to new user.
In another container i want to accesso to this db.
So i set up new container with a simply php script that create new table in this db.
I know that mysql container's ip is 172.17.0.2 so :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("172.17.0.2", "mattia", "prova", "prova");
```

Than using mysqli i create new table and all works fine.
But i think that connect to container using his ip address is not good.
Is there another way to specify db host? I tryed with the hostname of the mysql container but it doens't work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to link your docker containers together with --link flag in docker run command or using link feature in docker-compose. For instance:

```
docker run -d -name app-container-name --link mysql-container-name app-image-name
```

In this way docker will add the IP address of the mysql container into /etc/hosts file of your application container.
For a complete document refer to:
[MySQL Docker Containers: Understanding the basics](http://severalnines.com/blog/mysql-docker-containers-understanding-basics)

Comment: Links are now a [legacy option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links), and networks should be used instead.

Answer (score 63):

The `--link` flag is considered a legacy feature, you should use user-defined networks.

You can run both containers on the same network:

```
docker run -d --name php_container --network my_network my_php_image

docker run -d --name mysql_container --network my_network my_mysql_image
```

Every container on that network will be able to communicate with each other using the container name as hostname.

Comment: i had creat a new network as $ docker network create -d bridge mynetwork

and run my app container and mysql container on this network 
i try connect my node app to mysql container by container IP and port  but its not connect
eventhough my database is running in workbench fine

Comment: What if you have several containers and each one should connect to its own mysql container? 
F.I: bamboo-agent1 -->mysql1 , 
      bamboo-agent2 -->mysql2

Comment: @DimiDak just have them on two different networks. One pair (client+db) on one network, and the second pair on the other. You can create multiple networks for different projects.

Comment: works, just tested in 2021 with mysql 5.7 and laravel 7

Comment: i migrated laravel database successfully, changed DB_HOST=mysql_container

Answer (score 4):

If you are using docker-compose, than the database will be accessible under the service name.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

Then the database is accessible using: `postgres://db:5432`.
Here the service name is at the same time the hostname in the internal network.

Quote from docker docs:

> When you run docker-compose up, the following happens:
>
> 1. A network called myapp_default is created.
> 2. A container is created using web’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name web.
> 3. A container is created using db’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name db.

Source:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 3):

In your docker-compose.yml file add a link property to your webserver service:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links

Then in your query string, the host parameter's value is your database service name:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("database", "mattia", "prova", "prova");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
  - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
```

--

```
MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
```

Setting root host to `%` in docker-compose.yml file solves this issue.

> MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: By default, MySQL creates the 'root'@'localhost'
> account. This account can only be connected to from inside the
> container as described in Connecting to MySQL Server from within the
> Container. To allow root connections from other hosts, set this
> environment variable. For example, the value 172.17.0.1, which is the
> default Docker gateway IP, allows connections from the host machine
> that runs the container. The option accepts only one entry, but
> wildcards are allowed (for example, MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.*.*.* or
> MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%).

source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker_var_mysql-root-host