# Why I can't reach the pubsub emulator in a docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to run the pub/sub emulator in a docker container
But I can't reach it with my application in another docker

I've tried to set my env as
`ENV PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8085"`
or
`ENV PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST="pubsub:8085"`
with pubsub the name of the container running the emulator
Both of the containers are in the same network

I can ping the container running the emulator from the other one but when I try to create a topic I get the following error:

`503 failed to connect to all addresses`
The script to create the topic were working when I ran the emulator locally

Of course, I'm running the pubsub container with `-p 8085:8085`

Anyone would have an idea of the problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to mysql container from other container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429920/access-to-mysql-container-from-other-container)

Comment: Did you try 0.0.0.0:8085?

Comment: Did you create a docker network and attached both containers to that network? Otherwise they will not be able to talk to each other.

Comment: Yes, both container are attached to the same network

Comment: I did try with 0.0.0.0:8085, still not working

Comment: It's working when I use the network host

Comment: Pub/Sub library uses grpc instead of http, the `503 failed to connect to all addresses` is usually returned by the library when is trying to connect trough ipv6 but the endpoint is ipv4 (check this [thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/2638), could you please share the full error messages you are receiving?