# Access MySQL container from another containe

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Creating two containers, one contains the flask web app and the other has MySql installed. The web app in the first server needs to access the database in the other server.

**docker-compose.yml** file

web and db containers are linked in the compose file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    container_name: "web"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/web_build
    links: 
      - db
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
  db:
    container_name: "mysql"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/db_build
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'password'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
      - ./data:/data
```

My running containers

[image]

This is how web container's hosts file look like

```
root@9ee63128f6db:/code# cat /etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
**172.31.0.3      9ee63128f6db**
```

And the hosts file on db container

```
root@9acbf1743dca:/# cat /etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.31.0.2      9acbf1743dca
```

File **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

[image]

Installed Maria db on web container just to check connectivity.

```
apt install mariadb-server
```

DB container's IP is 172.31.0.2. When I try to connect I get the following error

```
root@9ee63128f6db:/code# mysql -u root -p'root' 172.31.0.2
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have gone through this [Access to mysql container from other container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429920/access-to-mysql-container-from-other-container) but it didn't help.

mysqld service is also not available.

- MySql latest version is pulled from MySQL docker image.

Comment: Maybe change `links: - db` to `depends_on: - db`...  just a guess

Comment: What connection information are you setting up in the `web` container, and what error are you getting when you use it?