# Cannot access MySQL from another container?

Tags: python, mysql, docker, containers, pymysql

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35429920/3552975) and many other tutorials but still cannot get the connection to work.

I created two containers and they are on the same network `net_a`, and the MySQL container was created using this command:

```
docker run -itd --name mysql_a -p 3319:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=passwd --network net_a mysql:latest
```

In the other container I want to access a MySQL database `db_a` using PyMySQL, and I tried this:

```
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host="mysql_a",
    user="root",
    password="passwd",
    database="db_a",
    port=3319, charset="utf8")
cur = connection.cursor()
```

But an error araises:

> --> 353             self.connect()
> 354
> 355     def **enter**(self):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py in
> connect(self, sock)
> 662                 if DEBUG:
> 663                     print(exc.traceback)
> --> 664                 raise exc
> 665
> 666             # If e is neither DatabaseError or IOError, It's a bug.
>
> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql_a'
> ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

I thought it was because they are not on the same network, then I ping the container name `mysql_a` from the other container and it shows this:

```
PING mysql_a (172.18.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mysql_a.net_a (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
64 bytes from mysql_a.net_a (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
64 bytes from mysql_a.net_a (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from mysql_a.net_a (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
```

I wonder why it doesn't work? Maybe the single-host bridge networks don't work in this scenario and I should learn something about multi-host overlay networks?

Answer (score 0):

I add this question and answer just for those who may have made the same mistake as me. I spent three nights figuring it out. If you have published the 3306 to services outside of Docker by mapping 3306 to a certain port N on the host's interface, you should not use port N, and the 3306 should be just Ok since two containers are in the same host and network(by setting the --network arg).

The host can be configured as the container name or its IP. And here is a case in Python scenario using PyMySQL:

```
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host="mysql_a", # or 172.18.0.3 in this case
    user="root",
    password="passwd",
    database="db_a",
    port=3306, charset="utf8")
cur = connection.cursor()
```

As the doc reads:

> To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers **which are not connected to the container’s network**, use the --publish or -p flag. This creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host to the **outside world**.